# UITableView does not scroll up every time I reload a tableview section

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a table with multiple section headers. What I am trying to do is every time I click on one of the section headers, section and section rows get updated using following code

`[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];`

Now, the problem is sections are reloaded and they come up but the tableView does not scroll up on that. Say my header section that I want to expand is at the bottom of the visible screen, every time I click on section header, it expands below that and is not visible to the user until and unless user scrolls the screen himself. I want the view to scroll up so that user could see the expanded view on the screen.

Any ideas how can i do that or any sample code would be appreciated.

Thanks
Vik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` table view method to scroll the table as needed.

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:someIndexPath atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionTop  animated:YES];
```

Provide the appropriate indexPath. There are other options for the scroll position if 'top' isn't quite what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Simple and effective. Works like a charm